# Testcontainers "JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool" on Gitlab pipeline

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis, testcontainers

I'm using **Testcontainers** for Redis cluster integration tests; though locally everything work as expected, but after creating a remote branch and pushing the code on Gitlab pipeline I'm getting the exception below. I have Cassandra and PostgreSQL that are working fine, but for Redis I'm getting the exception below.

**Update:**
previously with **fixedExposePort** the tests are working locally but now after removing the **fixedExposePort** even locally I'm getting the same error.

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisClusterMaxAttemptsException: No more cluster attempts left.
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:156)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runBinary(JedisClusterCommand.java:69)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisCluster.setex(BinaryJedisCluster.java:496)
        at redis.clients.jedis.commands.BinaryJedisClusterCommands.setex(BinaryJedisClusterCommands.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterStringCommands.setEx(JedisClusterStringCommands.java:175)
        ... 39 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
            at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:84)
            at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:366)
            at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:129)
            at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:118)
            ... 43 common frames omitted
        Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed to create socket.
            at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:110)
            at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:226)
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:135)
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:309)
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.initializeFromClientConfig(BinaryJedis.java:87)
            at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.<init>(BinaryJedis.java:292)
            at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.<init>(Jedis.java:167)
            at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:177)
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:889)
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
            at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:349)
            at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:75)
            ... 46 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
            at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
            at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
            at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
            at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:80)
            ... 57 common frames omitted
```

**Here is the Testcontainers configuration.**

```
public class RedisClusterContainer extends GenericContainer<RedisClusterContainer> {

    public RedisClusterContainer() {
        super("grokzen/redis-cluster:6.2.8");
        withEnv("IP", "0.0.0.0");
        addExposedPorts(7000, 7001, 7002, 7003, 7004, 7005);
    }

    public String getNodeAddress() {
        return Stream.of(7000, 7001, 7002, 7003, 7004, 7005)
                .map(port -> {
                    Integer mappedPort = getMappedPort(port);
                    return getHost() + ":" + mappedPort;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }
}
```

I have now added two tests that create the container in different ways without the **FixedExposedPort** but non of them is working.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
public class AbstractRedisClusterIT {
}
```

```
@Slf4j
class FirstRedisClusterIT extends AbstractRedisClusterIT {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    static {
        final RedisClusterContainer redisClusterContainer = new RedisClusterContainer();
        redisClusterContainer.start();

        String redisNodes = redisClusterContainer.getNodeAddress();

        log.info("Redis container started on nodes: {}", redisNodes);
        System.setProperty("spring.redis.cluster.nodes", redisNodes);
    }

    @Test
    void firstRedisTestContainerTest() {
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("secondRedisKey", "secondRedisValue", 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        String result = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("secondRedisKey");
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo("secondRedisValue");
    }
}
```

```
@Slf4j
class SecondRedisClusterIT extends AbstractRedisClusterIT {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    static {
        final GenericContainer<?> genericContainer = new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("grokzen/redis-cluster:6.2.8"))
                .withEnv("IP", "0.0.0.0")
                .withExposedPorts(7000, 7001, 7002, 7003, 7004, 7005);
        genericContainer.start();

        String redisNodes = Stream.of(7000, 7001, 7002, 7003, 7004, 7005)
                .map(port -> {
                    Integer mappedPort = genericContainer.getMappedPort(port);
                    return genericContainer.getHost() + ":" + mappedPort;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        System.setProperty("spring.redis.cluster.nodes", redisNodes);
        log.info("Redis container started on nodes: {}", redisNodes);
    }

    @Test
    void secondRedisTestContainerTest() {
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("firstRedisKey", "firstRedisValue", 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        String result = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("firstRedisKey");
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo("firstRedisValue");
    }
}
```

**Here is the connection factory configuration for the cluster.**

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class JedisConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.redis.cluster.nodes}")
    private String redisClusterNodes;

    @Value("${spring.redis.client-name:redis}")
    private String clientName;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        log.info("Cluster nodes: {}", redisClusterNodes);
        List<String> nodes = Arrays.stream(redisClusterNodes.split(",")).collect(toList());
        RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfig = new RedisClusterConfiguration(nodes);
        JedisClientConfiguration clientConfig = JedisClientConfiguration.builder().clientName(clientName).usePooling().build();
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(clusterConfig, clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        return new StringRedisTemplate(factory);
    }
}
```

**In the pipeline logs I could see the containers started.**

```
2022-12-15 14:14:19.804  INFO 87 --- [    Test worker] i.c.testenv.RedisContainerExtension      : Starting Redis container
    2022-12-15 14:14:19.814  INFO 87 --- [    Test worker]  [grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.7]         : Pulling docker image: grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.7. Please be patient; this may take some time but only needs to be done once.
    2022-12-15 14:14:20.170  INFO 87 --- [ream-2042455873]  [grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.7]         : Starting to pull image

................

2022-12-15 14:14:35.997  INFO 87 --- [    Test worker]  [grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.7]         : Creating container for image: grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.7
    2022-12-15 14:14:35.999  INFO 87 --- [ream-2042455873]  [grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.7]         : Pull complete. 17 layers, pulled in 15s (downloaded 176 MB at 11 MB/s)
    2022-12-15 14:14:36.335  INFO 87 --- [    Test worker]  [grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.7]         : Container grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.7 is starting: 47534017152ee0a974cf65d2030fbbab592da976a2d258613e5c27ad4b5b71e9
    2022-12-15 14:14:39.206  INFO 87 --- [    Test worker]  [grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.7]         : Container grokzen/redis-cluster:5.0.7 started in PT19.39715S
```

Even though the container is started and `getHost()` returns `docker` as the host but I'm still getting the above exception, does anyone knows what's I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `withFixedExposedPort`, this is likely not supported in your Gitlab-CI Docker setup. As Testcontainers maintainers, we *strongly* advise *against* using fixed ports in your tests, since those setups are not portable across environments.

Comment: Thanks @KevinWittek unfortunately when I tried without the `withFixedExposePort` I got the following exception.
`No reachable node in cluster; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisNoReachableClusterNodeException: No reachable node in cluster`

Comment: Please update your current code without using fixed ports to understand how you are using it.

Comment: Hi @KevinWittek I have updated the code and removed the `fixedExposePort`, but it seems like things get even worst, because now I'm getting the same exception in my local machine whereas before when the `fixedExposedPort` was used, it was only on Gitlab pipelines.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

An example based on [this github project](https://github.com/Hixon10/spring-redis-cluster-testcontainers/blob/master/src/test/java/ru/hixon/springredisclustertestcontainers/RedisConfig.java) can be found below

The example has been created using [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=data-redis,testcontainers)

The trick is in the `Config` class, `spring.data.redis.cluster.nodes` property is set with host and random ports. However, the client tries to resolve random ports and the original ones, so, the customizer will help to redirect the original ones to the random ones.

```java
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
class SpringBootRedisApplicationTests {

    @Container
    private static final RedisClusterContainer redisCluster = new RedisClusterContainer();

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.data.redis.cluster.nodes", redisCluster::getNodeAddress);
    }

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        this.redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("redisKey", "redisValue");
        String result = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("redisKey");
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo("redisValue");
    }

    static class RedisClusterContainer extends GenericContainer<RedisClusterContainer> {

        public RedisClusterContainer() {
            super("grokzen/redis-cluster:6.2.8");
            withEnv("IP", "0.0.0.0");
            addExposedPorts(7000, 7001, 7002, 7003, 7004, 7005);
            waitStrategy = Wait.forLogMessage(".*Cluster state changed: ok*\\n", 6);
        }

        public String getNodeAddress() {
            return Stream.of(7000, 7001, 7002, 7003, 7004, 7005)
                    .map(port -> {
                        Integer mappedPort = getMappedPort(port);
                        return getHost() + ":" + mappedPort;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        }

        public Map<Integer, Integer > ports() {
            return Map.of(7000, getMappedPort(7000),
                    7001, getMappedPort(7001),
                    7002, getMappedPort(7002),
                    7003, getMappedPort(7003),
                    7004, getMappedPort(7004),
                    7005, getMappedPort(7005));
        }

    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        ClientResourcesBuilderCustomizer customizer() {
            return builder -> {
                Function<HostAndPort, HostAndPort> mappingFn = hostAndPort -> {
                    if (redisCluster.ports().containsKey(hostAndPort.getPort())) {
                        Integer mappedPort = redisCluster.ports().get(hostAndPort.getPort());
                        return HostAndPort.of(hostAndPort.getHostText(), mappedPort);
                    }
                    return hostAndPort;
                };
                builder.socketAddressResolver(MappingSocketAddressResolver.create(mappingFn));
            };
        }

    }

}
```